# Retrieving second word to last but one word in a sentence in plsql

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle12c

I have written a program which executes properly in plsql but the output is wrong. Logically I donot see any issue with the code. Here is the code:

```
begin
  inpstr := rtrim(ltrim(regexp_replace(inp,'\s{2,}','')));
  lastpos := instr(inpstr,' ',-1);
  out3 := SUBSTR(inpstr, INSTR(inpstr,' ',-1) + 1);
  pos := instr(inpstr,' ');
  out1 := substr(inpstr,1,pos);
  out2 := substr(inpstr,pos,lastpos);
end;
```

O/P:

```
dbms_output.put_line('First Word:: '||out1||' '||'Second Word:: '||out2||' '||'Lastword:: '||out3);

PROCEDURE SPLITWORDS compiled
anonymous block completed
First Word:: Welcome  Second Word::  to the world of analyti Lastword:: analytics!
```

But the second word should retrieve 'to the world of' but it fetches analyti.

Could anyone tell me whats wrong with my code.

Thanks,
Dex.

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter of the `substr` function is the length of the substring, not the location of the ending character.  Subtracting `pos` from `lastpos` (see below) would allow your code to work.

```
out2 := substr(inpstr, pos, lastpos - pos);
```

Comment: I want all the words between first and the last word as out2

Comment: @Dex Oops, sorry.  I'll fix my answer

Answer (score 0):

When you assign `out2`, you at least have to substract `pos` from `lastPos`.

Because `lastPos` in your sample-text *"Welcome to the world of analytics!"* will be 24 and `pos` will have 8, so the substring from pos 8 with a length of 24 is ... right: *" to the world of analyti"*